# Is there any way to provide an alternative layout in a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I'm developping an application that will be used in combination with Microsoft Word. I anticipate that the user will resize the my application's window and Microsft Word's window so they don't overlap. When they do so they have the choice to put my application above (or bellow) Word or to put it in the right (or left) of Word.

In one case, my application's window will be much larger than high. In the other case, the window will be really narrow.

Is there any way to provide two layout for my window and switch from one to the other at runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use two completely separate templates, and apply a style to your Window.  That style can include a trigger, which uses a converter to convert the window's size to the template that it should use.

Thinking about it, the style might not be necessary either.  Perhaps you could just have `Template="{Binding Width, Converter=WidthToTemplateConverter}` in the window declaration...

Comment: Instead of a converter, you could use the TemplateSelector feature of WPF to pick the appropriate template. http://codingbandit.com/Blog/blog/wpf-data-templates-part-4-template-selectors/

Comment: Ooh, yes - didn't think of that.  Much better answer!  Post that properly so it can be upvoted ;P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a converter, you could use the TemplateSelector feature of WPF to pick the appropriate template.

Example:

http://codingbandit.com/Blog/blog/wpf-data-templates-part-4-template-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that you can load the XAML dynamically: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a53ff197-8703-4c6c-8726-45570304fb7b/

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at this blog post...it might fit your requirements
http://learnwpf.com/post/2011/08/09/Changing-the-DataTemplate-based-on-the-Available-Space-e28093-SizeBasedTemplateSelector.aspx